# Blender 3.5 Natural Scrolling

Tags: 3d-view

I recently upgraded to Blender 3.5, but one of the first things I noticed is that orbiting around an object is now inverted when scrolling around. I checked preferences, and it seems there's no way to invert scrolling. Has anyone found a way to invert orbit direction? If it helps, I'm on MacOS

Comment: Did you load the preferences from the previous version on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu Edit > Preferences.

In the Navigation tab, Zoom panel, you can find options to invert zoom directions, among other things you might like to take a look at:

[image: preferences]